# Android append and remove value from array child in firebase

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I add and remove a value in a array child of a child in firebase when onclick a button? After retrieving the user's name from the textbox, the name would be checked in firebase to append/remove based on the user.

```
"personas" : {
      "-L6zpuFOe7ptLtLLmZJm" : {
            "name" : "alicia",
            "hobbies" : [ "swimming", "running" ],
            "age" : "19"
             }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cannot perform a query across array members, to see if it contains a specific value in any position or to add/remove a record. Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write.

As usual with NoSQL databases: if you can't perform the use-case you want with your current data structure, you can typically change/expand your data structure to allow the use-case. The best practice is to instead of array to use maps

```
"-L6zpuFOe7ptLtLLmZJm" : {
    "name" : "alicia",
    "hobbies" : {
        "swimming": true
        "running" : true
    },
    "age" : "19"
}
```

You can also take a look, [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), for more informations.